# Getting files from shared folder

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'd like to access the files from a shared folder and then download them. The problem is that I only end up getting a "Getting Started" file and I don't know how to solve this. I tried several things, including making a query under the files().get function but with no success. This is my code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http


scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('server_secret.json', scopes)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()

files = results.get('files', [])

for f in files:
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the folder you refer to has a unique name, you could try something like the following:

```
def get_folder(name):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10,
        q=("name = '{0}'".format(name) +
           " and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"),
        corpora="user",
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink, " +
               "createdTime, modifiedTime)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        return None
    return items[0]
```

This function specifies the mime type corresponding to a Drive folder and returns the first result that matches the given name. If your folder name is not unique then you can modify it to return every matching result.

```
def get_folder_contents(folder_id):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    results = service.files().list(
        q=("'{0}' in parents".format(folder_id)),
        corpora="user",
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink, " +
               "createdTime, modifiedTime)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    return items
```

Once you know the `id` of the Drive folder, you can query for all the items that have that `id` in `parents`.
With these two functions you then could do something like:

```
folder = get_folder('my_folder_name')
folder_items = get_folder_contents(folder['id'])

for item in folder_items:
    # decide if you should download
    my_download_function(url=item['webContentLink'])
```

Comment: I've the folder name but I get no results in the case of the get_folder function. Could it be because it's a folder that has been shared to me?

Answer (score -1):

File.list has a paramater called q which lets you [search](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters). searching for 'sharedWithMe' will return everything that has been shared with your by other users.

> sharedWithMe   boolean =, !=   Files that are in the user's "Shared with me" collection.

```
def get_folder(name):
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10,
        q=("sharedWithMe"),
        corpora="user",
        fields="*").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
    if not items:
        return None
    return items[0]
```

That will give you everything thats been shared with you.

If you know the name of what you are looking for you can add that as well.

> sharedWithMe and name contains 'hello'

Comment: Would the -1 care to comment on the -1 on a 1.5 year old answer?